# How can I put a textbox inside a table data which rows have been appended/moved from another table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My question might be confusing, basically I have two tables in my ordering, one which is connected to a mysql database displaying the items i have in stock and the other (empty) table is where all my selected items go.

pic: http://tinypic.com/r/o89pn5/8

Now, everytime i click the button beside each row on the top table, it transfers the rows to the lower table

pic: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=290sfw2&s=8#.U7LMjpSSzTo

Now notice on the lower table I have another column named "**Quantity**". Can anyone show me how to fill this column with textboxes? Thanks a lot to anyone who can help me. I'm just staring to learn Javascript/JQuery.

Please feel free to ask me more questions in case my question is not clear.

Code for the tables:

```
 <!-- Table 1(inventory table) -->
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","purchasing");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_inventory");

    echo "<table id='table1' class='inventory' border='3'>
    <tr>
    <th>Check</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Product Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Stock</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td> <button class='btn'>order</button> </td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['prod_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['prod_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['stock'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con);
?>  
<br/><br/>
<!-- Table 2(ordered items table) -->
<table id="table2" class="inventory" border="3">
<tr>
    <th>Check</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Product Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Stock</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
</tr>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The scripts:

```
<script>

$(".btn").click(function () {
// get the row containing this link 
var row = $(this).closest("tr");

// find out in which table it resides
var table = $(this).closest("table");

// move it
row.detach();

if (table.is("#table1")) {
    $("#table2").append(row);
}
else {
    $("#table1").append(row);
}

// draw the user's attention to it
row.fadeOut();
row.fadeIn();
});

</script>
```

Comment: instead of images show your html or better make a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, this may work, but it won't remember whichever value has been put in the text box if a user removes the `row` from `#table2` and put it back later on.

```
if (table.is("#table1")) {
    row.append('<td><input type="text" class="quantity" /></td>');
    $("#table2").append(row);
}
else {
    row.find('td:last').remove();
    $("#table1").append(row);
}
```

If you have good [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) support, you should be able to use inputs of type `number` instead of a plain text box.

As an extra, you probably want to have the fadeout/fadein happen around the row move. You may implement it as follow:

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr');
var table = $(this).closest('table');
row.fadOut(300, function(){
    row.detach();
    if (table.is("#table1")) {
        row.append('<td><input type="text" class="quantity" /></td>');
        row.find('.btn').html('remove');
        $("#table2").append(row);
    }
    else {
        row.find('td:last').remove();
        row.find('.btn').html('order');
        $("#table1").append(row);
    }
    row.fadeIn(300);
});
```

Comment: I tried your code and it was ALMOST there, i just encountered a problem. everytime i remove a row from the lower table, this happens: tinypic.com/r/if7sy0/8 Notice the red arrow. An extra column or space is added beside the last td. any idea what causes this?

Comment: Should work now: I wasn't testing with an `input` in the last `td`.

Answer (score 2):

After this line:

```
$("#table2").append(row);
```

just append textbox in last `tr` last `td` like this:

```
$("#table2").find("tr:last").find("td:last").append('<input type="text" class="quantity" />');
```

Comment: You need to take care of the other case as well, I think.

Comment: Unless the row is automatically truncated to fit a smaller table, you should remove the extra column when the row is moved back from table2 to table1.

Comment: where OP mentioned that row will be moved back to upper table

Comment: I made an anwser of my own, perhaps you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @didierc table1 does not have column for quantity

Comment: OP here @didierc is right, the rows from the lower table can be moved back to the upper table.

Comment: But where is column for quantity @Killme

Comment: @EhsanSajjad The column Quantity is automatically not included when returning the selected row back to the top table :)

Answer (score 2):

JQuery gives you a few different ways to dynamically add elements to the page. In this case, if you wanted to add a text input to a td element you could do something simple like this:

```
<script>
$('table#table2 td.quantity').append('<input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="0" />");
</script>
```

You can also build elements using various JQuery methods and then append the the JQuery object directly:

```
<script>
  var inputObj = $('<input />');
  inputObj.attr('type','text').val('0').attr('name','quantity').attr('id','quantity');
  $('table#table2 td.quantity').append( inputObj );
</script>
```

Comment: this may be too much but is it ok if you tell me where i can put your code? I first tried simply copying it and nothing happens when i click the buttons, then i modified it a bit then the textbox appears at the bottom of t he table and not inside the Quantity column. Thanks a lot for the answer :)

Comment: Well you've already got a nice reference to the tr you need to work with via the `row` variable. I would make the append call using the row variable as context right after your `row.detach()` call. Something like `$('td:last',row).append('<input ... />');`. Basically you need to make sure you are selecting the right td when you append the input. You might consider adding a CSS class to the td which will contain the quantity input to make this a little easier.